# Teleport some HTML from one place to another

Tags: javascript, html

I have something like this (abstract example)

```
<div id="placeN1">
    <div id="myDiv" style="color:gray;">
        <div id="innerDiv">Some content</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="placeN2">
    I want to move myDiv here    
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myDivElement = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    myDivElement.onclick = function(){ alert('click'); };
</script>
```

**I want to move one Html element (with all styles and events that where attached) form one place to another, how to do that in pure javascript?**

Comment: you can get and set innerHtml property of DOM elements

Comment: i can use set and set innerHtml, but i will lose all attached events...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will move the the element, but it depends on how your CSS and JS Events are declared/attached,if they will still function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myDivElement = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    var div2 = document.getElementById('placeN2');

    myDivElement.onclick = function(){ div2.appendChild(myDivElement);};
</script>
```

Comment: it seems that your example forks in my case.. tnx